# UIscrollView not work

Tags: ios, swift, scrollview

I downloaded this code to a chart:

https://github.com/tmdvs/CoreGraphicsGraph

I'm trying to insert a horizontal and vertical scroll view programmatically.

I tried to do this but it does not work:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        parser.delegate = self
        parser.parse {
            let myData = [
                ["label" : "2000",   "value" : NSNumber(int:15)],
                ["label" : "2001",  "value" : NSNumber(int:30)],
                ["label" : "2002",  "value" : NSNumber(int:7)],
                ["label" : "2003", "value" : NSNumber(int:60)],
                ["label" : "2004",   "value" : NSNumber(int:30)],
                ["label" : "2005",   "value" : NSNumber(int:15)],
                ["label" : "2006",   "value" : NSNumber(int:45)],
                ["label" : "2007",   "value" : NSNumber(int:45)],
                ["label" : "2008",   "value" : NSNumber(int:50)],
                ["label" : "2009",   "value" : NSNumber(int:60)],
                ["label" : "2010",   "value" : NSNumber(int:70)],
                ["label" : "2011",   "value" : NSNumber(int:80)],
                ["label" : "2012",   "value" : NSNumber(int:90)],
                ["label" : "2013",   "value" : NSNumber(int:100)],
                ["label" : "2014",   "value" : NSNumber(int:200)],
                ["label" : "2015",   "value" : NSNumber(int:300)],
                ["label" : "2016",   "value" : NSNumber(int:400)],
                ["label" : "2017",   "value" : NSNumber(int:500)],
                ["label" : "2018",   "value" : NSNumber(int:600)],
                ["label" : "2019",   "value" : NSNumber(int:700)],
                ["label" : "2020",   "value" : NSNumber(int:800)],
                ["label" : "2021",   "value" : NSNumber(int:900)],
                ] as NSArray

            // ScrollView
            let scrollView : UIScrollView = UIScrollView(frame : CGRect(x:1000, y:(1000), width: (1000), height: (1000) ))
            scrollView.scrollEnabled = true
            scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width:1234, height: 5678)



            // Textview
            let textView : UITextView = UITextView(frame : CGRect(x:400, y:(500), width: (100), height: (100) ))
            textView.text = "SeriesKey"

            // graph
            let graph = GraphView(frame: CGRectMake(50, 100, 900, 300), data: myData)
            // Add sub view
            self.view.addSubview(textView)
            self.view.addSubview(graph)
            self.view.addSubview(scrollView)    
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions? Thank You.

Comment: And *what* does not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example is not working, because your `UIScrollView` has no content. To make it work, add the content you want to show to your scroll view, e.g.:

```
let scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100))

let contentView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 200, 200))
contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
contentView.layer.borderWidth = 10.0

// This is important!
scrollView.addSubview(contentView)

scrollView.contentSize = view.bounds.size
scrollView.scrollEnabled = true

addSubview(scrollView)
```

This will give you a scrollable black subview with a nice red border. Also, please have a look at the [Scroll View Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/CreatingBasicScrollViews/CreatingBasicScrollViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008179-CH101-SW1) provided by Apple.